# Excel: Sum of sumproducts

Tags: arrays, excel, matrix, product

In a math context I have the sum over two indices of the product of a one-index variable with a two-indices variable.

In the Excel context, suppose I have the range `A1:C1` and a matrix `A2:C6` and all I want to do is:

```
sumproduct(A1:C1;A2:C2)+sumproduct(A1:C1;A3:C3)+sumproduct(A1:C1;A4:C4)+sumproduct(A1:C1;A5:C5)+sumproduct(A1:C1;A6:C6).
```

Is there any automated way to do it using formulas?

Comment: Please *show* some example input, along with the desired output and how exactly this is to be calculated. Right now I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:C1*A2:C6)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Although I think this opens up a new question that I had never thought of before on the difference between SUMPRODUCT(_;_) and SUMPRODUCT(_*_). The first dows not work here; the second one does. Thanks anyway

Comment: This first would multiply ALL the listed arrays together, then adds the results. The second only performs multiplication between the arrays you explicitly designate, and adds the rest, then adds the results.

Comment: .....and if you use ; between the ranges/arrays then all have to be the same size, so that doesn't work here because A1:C1 and A2:C6 are obviously different sizes

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but can't you just write

```
=SUMPRODUCT($A$1:$C$1;A2:C2)
```

then copy it down and sum up the results?